# How do I force an html file to open in the browser instead of downloading? (Classic Google Sites)

Tags: html, google-sites

I'm using classic google sites and uploaded an html file. However, when I click on the link instead of opening directly on a new tab it tries to download it. So, how can I force that by clicking the link it opens directly in the browser?

Link location:

http://www.rodriguesloures.com/econometrics.html?attredirects=0&d=1

Code:

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle"><img alt="" src="https://sites.google.com/site/arloures/julia-language.png" style="vertical-align:middle" title="julia" width="25" height="25" border="0"> <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/arloures/econometrics.html?attredirects=0&amp;d=1" target="_blank">Applied Econometrics using Julia</a></div>
```

Thanks for you feedback!

Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

You probably generated your html file with PANDOC and uploaded it to your site as page attachment (using `Add file` link). Google treats all attachments as files for download only.

What you can try to do is:

1. create a new page called econometrics for example
2. at the new page's **EDIT pane** click `<html>` button, *Edit HTML* popup window should be open now
3. Paste your entire HTML content into text area and hit update button

Now, all links to this page will open your HTML and not download it